# webservice is returning funny looking xml

Tags: asp.net, web-services, xml-serialization

My web service return a `Dictionary<int, TrialBalanceAccountSummaryModel>` structure, but the return xml string look funny.

Please see the image at below, how do it remove the node < KeyValueOfintReport[random_char] >, and replace it with a normal node like < Report > ?

P.S. Stop draws legs to a snake, Microsoft!

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Reports>
           <KeyValueOfintReportLjh4bohd>
              <Key>10000001</Key>
              <Value>
                 <AccountNo>10000001</AccountNo>
                 <AccumulatedAmount>560000</AccumulatedAmount>
                 <CompanyCode>17</CompanyCode>
                 <FiscalYear>2012</FiscalYear>
                 <Period01Amount>560000</Period01Amount>
                 <Period02Amount>0</Period02Amount>
                 <Period03Amount>0</Period03Amount>
                 <Period04Amount>0</Period04Amount>
                 <Period05Amount>0</Period05Amount>
                 <Period06Amount>0</Period06Amount>
                 <Period07Amount>0</Period07Amount>
                 <Period08Amount>0</Period08Amount>
                 <Period09Amount>0</Period09Amount>
                 <Period10Amount>0</Period10Amount>
                 <Period11Amount>0</Period11Amount>
                 <Period12Amount>0</Period12Amount>
                 <Period13Amount>0</Period13Amount>
                 <Period14Amount>0</Period14Amount>
                 <Period15Amount>0</Period15Amount>
              </Value>
           </KeyValueOfintReportLjh4bohd>
           <KeyValueOfintReportLjh4bohd>
              <Key>10000002</Key>
              <Value>
                 <AccountNo>10000002</AccountNo>
                 <AccumulatedAmount>191234</AccumulatedAmount>
                 <CompanyCode>17</CompanyCode>
                 <FiscalYear>2012</FiscalYear>
                 <Period01Amount>191234</Period01Amount>
                 <Period02Amount>0</Period02Amount>
                 <Period03Amount>0</Period03Amount>
                 <Period04Amount>0</Period04Amount>
                 <Period05Amount>0</Period05Amount>
                 <Period06Amount>0</Period06Amount>
                 <Period07Amount>0</Period07Amount>
                 <Period08Amount>0</Period08Amount>
                 <Period09Amount>0</Period09Amount>
                 <Period10Amount>0</Period10Amount>
                 <Period11Amount>0</Period11Amount>
                 <Period12Amount>0</Period12Amount>
                 <Period13Amount>0</Period13Amount>
                 <Period14Amount>0</Period14Amount>
                 <Period15Amount>0</Period15Amount>
              </Value>
           </KeyValueOfintReportLjh4bohd>

        </Reports>
```

Comment: Nobody can ready your image. How about posting the actual XML?

Comment: Is this WCF, ASMX, something else?  Based on the element names, I'm thinking it's WCF......

Comment: @Tim it is mvc 4 web api